# Python equivalent for sending and receiving data from a socket connection

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets

I have a Java socket server instance running from which I want to receive and send data using python. I also have Java equivalent code to do the task, but rewriting the same process in Python is not doing the job and the connection breaks after server timeout.

```
public class ctakesSocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        DataInputStream ois = null;
        socket = new Socket("10.2.1.21", 6700);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        String string = "Blood Pressure";
        System.out.println("Sending request to Socket Server");
        OutputStream oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        oStream.write(string.getBytes());
        socket.shutdownOutput();

        long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        InputStream iStream = socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; 
        int numRead = 0;
        List<Byte> lstBytes = new ArrayList<>();
        while((numRead = iStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRead; i++) {
                lstBytes.add(bytes[i]);
            }
        }
        
        byte[] result = new byte[lstBytes.size()];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < lstBytes.size(); i++) {
            result[i] = lstBytes.get(i);
        }

        long finished = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Message: " + new String(result));
        System.out.println("Time taken: " + ((finished-started)/1000) + " minutes");
        socket.close();
        
    }
}
```

Python Code written:

```
import socket


def client_program():
    host = '10.2.1.21'
    port = 6700

    client_socket = socket.socket()  # instantiate
    client_socket.connect((host, port))  # connect to the server
    print('Çonnected')
    message = input(" -> ")  + '\n' # take input
    print(message)
    while message.lower().strip() != 'bye':
        client_socket.send(message.encode())  # send message
        client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()  # receive response

        print('Received from server: ' + data)  # show in terminal

        message = input(" -> ")  # again take input

    client_socket.close()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `shutdown`? Can you pass `SHUT_WR` to it?

Comment: Why is the socket send shutdown after sending?  If you do that, on the next iteration of the loop, transmission will be disabled.

Comment: @cup As far as I know, we need to shutdown the write operation before we start receiving data. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MousamSingh you don't need to close it.

Comment: @abhiarora On passing socket.SHUT_WR to client_socket.shutdown() it again waits for response for some time and fails after giving timeout error.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @MousamSingh: not closing  or shutdown the socket. Just writing and reading. Once the socket is shutdown for writing you cannot write any more data, i.e. the loop make no sense then. This is wrong in the Java code too. Also not that `send` is not guaranteed to write all data (check the return value) and `recv` is not guaranteed to read all data (check the return value). Also TCP is no message protocol but just cares about bytes - to determine where a message starts and ends is up to the application and you might need to have some message boundary or similar.